# Prob. 19, Chap. 5, in Baby Rudin: If $f$ is defined in $(-1, 1)$, $f^\prime(0)$ exists, $-1<\alpha_n<\beta_n<1$, and . . .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

Here is Prob. 19, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f$ is defined in $(-1, 1)$ and $f^\prime(0)$ exists. Suppose $-1 < \alpha_n < \beta_n < 1$, $\alpha_n \to 0$, and $\beta \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Define the difference quotients $$ D_n = \frac{f\left(\beta_n\right)-f\left(\alpha_n\right)}{\beta_n-\alpha_n}.$$ 
>   Prove the following statements:
>
> (a) If $\alpha_n < 0 < \beta_n$, then $\lim D_n = f^\prime(0)$.
>
> (b) If $0 < \alpha_n < \beta_n$ and $\left\{ \beta_n / (\beta_n-\alpha_n) \right\}$ is bounded, then $\lim D_n = f^\prime(0)$.
>
> (c) If $f^\prime$ is continuous in $(-1, 1)$, then $\lim D_n = f^\prime(0)$.
>
> Give an example in which $f$ is differentiable in $(-1, 1)$ (but $f^\prime$ is not continuous at $0$) and in which $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$ tend to $0$ in such a way that $\lim D_n$ exists but is different from $f^\prime(0)$.

My Attempt:

> Part (a): Since $$f^\prime(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}$$ exists, so, given any real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \left| \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} - f^\prime(0) \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \tag{1} $$
>   for all $x \in (-1, 1)$ for which $0 < |x| < \delta$.
>
> Now as $\alpha_n \to 0$ and $\beta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so we can find natural numbers $M$ and $N$ such that 
>   $$ \left| \alpha_n \right| < \delta \ \mbox{ for all } n > M,$$ 
>   and 
>   $$ \left| \beta_n \right| < \delta  \ \mbox{ for all } n > N,$$ 
>   So 
>   $$ \left| \alpha_n \right| < \delta  \ \mbox{ and } \left| \beta_n \right| < \delta \ \mbox{ for all } n > \max \left\{ M, N \right\}. \tag{2} $$
>
> As $\alpha_n < 0 < \beta_n$, so we have $0 < - \alpha_n < \beta_n - \alpha_n$ and $ 0 < \beta_n < \beta_n - \alpha_n$, which imply 
>   $$ 0 < \frac{\beta_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } < 1 \ \mbox{ and } \ 0 < \frac{ - \alpha_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } < 1. \tag{3} $$ 
>   Now
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> D_n &=  \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f \left( \alpha_n \right) }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } \\
> &= \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) + f(0) -  f \left( \alpha_n \right) }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } \\
> &= \frac{f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n} + \frac{ f(0) -  f \left( \alpha_n \right)}{\beta_n - \alpha_n} \\
> &= \frac{\beta_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n } + \frac{ - \alpha_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n} \frac{ f \left( \alpha_n \right) - f(0) }{ \alpha_n }.
> \end{align}
> $$
>   So, for all $n > \max \left\{ M, N \right\}$ [Refer to (2) above.], we obtain
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> & \left| D_n - f^\prime(0) \right| \\
> &= \left| \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f \left( \alpha_n \right) }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } - f^\prime(0) \right| \\
> &= \left| \frac{\beta_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n } + \frac{ - \alpha_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n} \frac{ f \left( \alpha_n \right) - f(0) }{ \alpha_n } - f^\prime(0) \right| \\
> &= \left| \frac{\beta_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } \left[ \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n } - f^\prime(0) \right]  +  \frac{ - \alpha_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n} \left[ \frac{ f \left( \alpha_n \right) - f(0) }{ \alpha_n } - f^\prime(0) \right] \right| \\
> &\leq \frac{\beta_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } \left| \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n } - f^\prime(0) \right|  +  \frac{ - \alpha_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n} \left| \frac{ f \left( \alpha_n \right) - f(0) }{ \alpha_n } - f^\prime(0)  \right| \qquad \mbox{ [ using (3) ] } \\
> &\leq \left| \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n } - f^\prime(0) \right|  + \left| \frac{ f \left( \alpha_n \right) - f(0) }{ \alpha_n } - f^\prime(0)  \right| \qquad \mbox{ [ using (3) again ] }  \\
> &= \frac{\varepsilon}{4} + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \qquad \mbox{ [ using (1) and (2) ] } \\
> &< \varepsilon. 
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   Thus, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a natural number $K \colon= \max\left\{ M, N \right\}$ such that $$ \left| D_n - f^\prime(0) \right| < \varepsilon $$ for all natural numbers $n > K$. Hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty} D_n = 0.$$

Am I right?

> Part (b): If $0 < \alpha_n < \beta_n$, then $$0 < \frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n - \alpha_n} < \frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n - \alpha_n}; \tag{4}$$ furthermore if there is a real number $r > 0$ such that $$\frac{\beta_n }{\beta_n - \alpha_n } \leq r,$$ then we also have $$ \frac{\alpha_n }{\beta_n - \alpha_n } \leq r.$$
>   Now as $f^\prime(0) = \lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{ f(x) - f(0) }{x-0}$ exists, so, for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that $$\left| \frac{ f(x) - f(0) }{x-0} - f^\prime(0) \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4r} \ \mbox{ for all real numbers } x \in (-1, 1) \ \mbox{ for which } \ 0 < | x | < \delta. \tag{5} $$ 
>   And, since $\alpha_n \to 0$ and $\beta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, therefore we can find natural numbers $M$ and $N$ such that 
>   $$ \left| \alpha_n \right| < \delta \ \mbox{ for all natural numbers } n > M, \tag{6} $$
>   and 
>   $$ \left| \beta_n \right| < \delta \ \mbox{ for all natural numbers } n > N. \tag{7} $$
>   So, for all natural numbers $n > \max\left\{ M, N \right\}$, we see that 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> & \left| D_n - f^\prime(0) \right| \\
> &= \left| \frac{\beta_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } \left[ \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n } - f^\prime(0) \right]  +  \frac{ - \alpha_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n} \left[ \frac{ f \left( \alpha_n \right) - f(0) }{ \alpha_n } - f^\prime(0) \right] \right| \\
> &\leq \frac{\beta_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } \left| \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n } \right| + \frac{  \alpha_n }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n} 
> \left| \frac{ f \left( \alpha_n \right) - f(0) }{ \alpha_n } - f^\prime(0) \right| \qquad \mbox{ [ using (4) ] } \\
> &\leq r \left| \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f(0) }{ \beta_n } \right| + r \left| \frac{ f \left( \alpha_n \right) - f(0) }{ \alpha_n } - f^\prime(0) \right| \qquad \mbox{ [ using our hypothesis ] } \\
> &< r \frac{\varepsilon}{4r} + r \frac{\varepsilon}{4r} \qquad \mbox{ [ using (5), (6), and (7) above ] } \\
> &< \varepsilon.
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   Since $\varepsilon$ was an arbitrary positive real number, therefore it follows that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} D_n = f^\prime(0),$$ 
>   as required.

Am I right?

> Part (c): For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as $-1 < \alpha_n < \beta_n < 1$ and as $f^\prime$ is continuous in $(-1, 1)$, so $f$ satisfies the hypothesis of the mean value theorem on the interval $\left[ \alpha_n, \beta_n \right]$. So, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can find a real number $\gamma_n \in \left( \alpha_n, \beta_n \right)$ such that $$ D_n = \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f \left( \alpha_n \right) }{ \beta_n - \alpha_n } = f^\prime\left(\gamma_n\right). $$
>   Now as $\alpha_n < \gamma_n < \beta_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and as $\alpha_n \to 0$ and $\beta_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so by the sandwiching theorem we can conclude that $\gamma_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and since $f^\prime$ is continuous in $(-1, 1)$ and hence at $x=0$, therefore we can conclude that $f^\prime\left(\gamma_n\right) \to f^\prime(0)$ as $n \to \infty$; that is, $D_n \to f^\prime(0)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Am I right?

> Let $f$ be defined on $(-1, 1)$ by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \ & \ (x \neq 0), \\ 0 \ & \ (x=0). \end{cases} $$ Let $$\alpha_n = \frac{1}{2\pi (n + 1/4)}, \qquad \beta_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi n}  \qquad \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}.$$ 
>   Then $$ f^\prime(x) = \begin{cases} 2x \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) + x^2 \cos \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \ & \ (x \neq 0), \\ 0 \ & \ (x=0). \end{cases} $$ 
>   Moreover, $$0 < \alpha_n < \beta_n < 1 \ \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N},$$ and $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n = 0, \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} \beta_n = 0.$$ 
>   Now 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> D_n &= \frac{ f\left( \beta_n \right) - f\left( \alpha_n \right)   }{\beta_n - \alpha_n } \\ 
> &= \frac{ - \frac{1}{4 \pi^2 (n+1/4)^2 } }{\frac{1}{2 \pi n}  -  \frac{1}{2\pi (n + 1/4)} } \\
> &= - \frac{ 1}{2 \pi } \frac{  \frac{1}{(n+1/4)^2} }{ \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1/4}  } \\
> &= - \frac{ 1}{2 \pi } \frac{ \frac{1}{n+1/4} }{ \frac{1/4}{ n }  } \\
> &= - \frac{ 1}{2 \pi }\frac{16 n}{4n + 1} \\
> &= - \frac{ 8 }{ \pi } \frac{1}{ 4+1/n }.
> \end{align}
> $$
>   So 
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} D_n = - \frac{2}{\pi} \neq f^\prime(0).$$

Am I right?

Are my proofs correct and rigorous enough for Rudin? If not, then where are the pitfalls?

Is my example appropriate in the situation described by Rudin? If so, is my calculation correct also?

Comment: In your solutions, are there any steps you aren't sure about? It is easier to ask a specific question about what you've done rather than a generic, "Am I right?"

Comment: @Clayton as far as I can see it, my solutions are correct, but I'd like to confirm from the Math SE community if that's really the case.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend this method: For  (a): When $0\ne x\in (-1,1)$ we have $$\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0) +d(x)$$ where $\lim_{x\to 0}d(x)=0.$ So we have  $$f(x)-f(0)=xf'(0)+xd(x).$$  Let $-1<a<0<b<1$. We have $$f(b)-f(a)=
[f(b)-f(0)]-[f(a)-f(0)]=[bf'(0)+bd(b)]-[af'(0)+ad(a)]=(b-a)f'(0)+[bd(b)-ad(a)]
.$$ Now  $|b-a|=|b|+|a|$.

And $|bd(b)|\leq (|b|+|a|)|d(b)|.$

And $|ad(a)|\leq (|b|+|a|)|d(a)|.$ So we have $$|bd(b)-ad(a)|\leq |bd(b)|+|ad(a)|\leq (|b|+|a|)(|d(b)|+|d(a)|).$$ $$\text {Therefore }\quad \left| \frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-f'(0)\right|=\left| \frac {bd(b)-ad(a)}{b-a}\right|=$$ $$\frac {|bd(b)-ad(a)|}{|b|+|a|}\leq \frac {(|b|+|a|)(|d(b)|+
|d(a)|)}{|b|+|a|}=|d(b)|+|d(a)|$$ And $|d(b)|+|d(b))$ converges to $0$ as $\max (b,-a)=\max (|b|,|a|)\to 0.$

Comment: thank you so much for your beautiful answer! But can you please also take a look at my solution and comment on whether there is any problem with it?

Comment: Your proofs of (a) and (c) and the example after (c)  are correct. I did not read (b). Your proof of (a) and mine are basically the same proof.